# How can I see my uncategorized friends in the new Steam friends UI?

Tags: steam

I get a lot of friend requests, and I use a combination of categories and nicknames to help gauge who stays and who goes. In short, if they belong in a category, they stay on my friends list. Everyone in the default "Friends" section gets removed after several weeks if I don't interact with them. However, with the new Steam friends UI, I can't seem to find any way to get the default "Friends" category back.

How can I see all my Steam friends that don't belong to a category?

Answer (score 4):

Click the gear in the upper-right of the friend's list, then make sure "Hide categorized friends in Online/Offline friends" is enabled

[image: Gear]

[image: Hide online/offline friends]

Then only uncategorized friends will show up under 'Online Friends' *(at the bottom of the friend's list)*

Comment: Also possible to hide the "game categories" [from people playing stuff](https://redd.it/96n4rv), though there's no controls for it still apparently.